# carouFredSel slider - prev,next and pagination not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, caroufredsel

I am using the `carouFredSel` jquery plugin for a website I'm making. I'm having some issues with the "**prev**", "**next**" and "**pagination**" containers. The images show up and start sliding but I cant navigate (prev/next) and I cant see the pagination itself..

You can see the page here: http://goo.gl/pJLNN

The slider is on the top. Caroufredsel is initialized in bbody.js upon DOM ready. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to correct the images positions you need to add or change the absolute position of every image container.

Since the type of animation you chosen is Crossfade then all the images must be in top of each other to make it work, otherwise by default the are next to each other.

**So in the css put this:**

```
#rotate > div {
float: left;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 650px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
}
```

**To correct next and prev you need to make a small fix to the js, this is the correct way of calleing the buttons**

```
prev: {
       button  : "#msprev"
},
next: {
       button  : "#msnext"
},
```

**The same happens to pagination, correct it:**

```
pagination: {
    container: '#pager'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This fixed my problems.
I was very surprised, since I used the configuration tool on carouFredSel's site and just copy-pasted the code.. guess they have a bug over there. Cheers, mate

Comment: Some documents are not up to date, :D have had the same problems.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else facing this issue, another reason for the prev, next & pagination links not working is that the element IDs may have been duplicated somewhere else on your page. I had

```
prev: {
       button  : "#prev3"
},
next: {
       button  : "#next3"
},
```

There two elements with `id="prev3` on the page. Same for `id="next3"`. Once I changed the IDs to make them unique, the navigation started working correctly.